# Am I doing nested joins incorrectly?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Folks! I am scratching my head on this one. Right when I add UserRole part in last join I start seeing this error. What am I doing wrong? Is there a limit on number of nested joins in MySQL?

### Error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON Opportunity.AccountId = AccountD.Id' at line 31
```

### Table Structure

```
Opportunity
-----------
Id, Name, AccountId, OwnerId

Account
-------
Id,Name,OwnerId

User
----
Id,Name,UserRoleId

UserRole
--------
Id,Name

RecordType
----------
Id,Name
```

### SQL

```
SELECT 
Opportunity.Id AS 'Opportunity_ID',
Opportunity.Opportunity_Number__c AS 'Opportunity_Number__c',
UserA.Name AS 'Opportunity_Owner',
Opportunity.Name AS 'Opportunity_Name',
Opportunity.Probability AS 'Opportunity_Probability',
Opportunity.StageName AS 'Opportunity_Stage',
Opportunity.Amount AS 'Opportunity_Amount',
Opportunity.CloseDate AS 'Opportunity_CloseDate',
Opportunity.Roll_Out_End_Formula__c AS 'Opportunity_Rollout_End_Date',
RecordTypeA.Name AS 'Record_Type',
Opportunity.Division__c AS 'Division',
Pricebook2.Name AS 'Price_Book',
Opportunity.Won_Date__c AS 'Opportunity_Won_Date',
Opportunity.CreatedDate AS 'Opportunity_Created_Date',
AccountA.Id AS 'Account_ID',
AccountA.Name AS 'Account_Name',
AccountA.Type AS 'Account_Type',
RecordTypeB.Name AS 'Account_Record_Type',
AccountA.Key_Account__c AS 'Key_Account',
UserB.Name AS 'Account_Owner',
UserB.Sales_Team__c AS 'Account_Owner_Sales_Team',
UserRoleA.Name AS 'Account_Owner_User_Role'
FROM Opportunity
LEFT JOIN User UserA ON Opportunity.OwnerId = UserA.Id
LEFT JOIN RecordType RecordTypeA ON Opportunity.RecordTypeId = RecordTypeA.Id
LEFT JOIN Pricebook2 ON Opportunity.Pricebook2Id = Pricebook2.Id
LEFT JOIN Account AccountA ON Opportunity.AccountId = AccountA.Id
LEFT JOIN Account AccountB JOIN RecordType RecordTypeB ON AccountB.RecordTypeId = RecordTypeB.Id ON Opportunity.AccountId = AccountB.Id
LEFT JOIN Account AccountC JOIN User UserB ON AccountC.OwnerId = UserB.Id ON Opportunity.AccountId = AccountC.Id
LEFT JOIN Account AccountD JOIN User UserC JOIN UserRole UserRoleA ON UserC.UserRoleId = UserRoleA.Id ON AccountD.OwnerId = UserC.Id ON Opportunity.AccountId = AccountD.Id
LIMIT 5\G
```

Comment: `Account[B|C|D]` do not appear to have join conditions...er, or rather they are in the wrong place. They also appear to be redundant since they are all joined by the same Opportunity.AccountId.

Comment: What do you mean by "*nested joins*"?

Comment: I don't see a nested join

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do nested joins to your "Account" instances, you have to use parentheses.

```
LEFT JOIN Account AccountA ON Opportunity.AccountId = AccountA.Id
LEFT JOIN (Account AccountB JOIN RecordType RecordTypeB ON AccountB.RecordTypeId = RecordTypeB.Id) 
    ON Opportunity.AccountId = AccountB.Id
LEFT JOIN (Account AccountC JOIN User UserB ON AccountC.OwnerId = UserB.Id) 
    ON Opportunity.AccountId = AccountC.Id
LEFT JOIN (Account AccountD JOIN User UserC ON AccountD.OwnerId = UserC.Id JOIN UserRole UserRoleA ON UserC.UserRoleId = UserRoleA.Id)
    ON Opportunity.AccountId = AccountD.Id
```

Edit: I fixed the last line (the one with AccountD).

Comment: Still same error. If I reduce one level of join it works.

Comment: Bill Karwin for the win :)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the sort of code that gets auto-generated when you use the Query Designer (tends to be a dead giveaway actually)

That said it does work, it's just difficult to read.

Replace your from clause with the following and see if you're still having problems...

```
FROM 
    Opportunity
    LEFT JOIN User UserA 
        ON Opportunity.OwnerId = UserA.Id
    LEFT JOIN RecordType RecordTypeA 
        ON Opportunity.RecordTypeId = RecordTypeA.Id
    LEFT JOIN Pricebook2 
        ON Opportunity.Pricebook2Id = Pricebook2.Id
    LEFT JOIN Account AccountA 
        ON Opportunity.AccountId = AccountA.Id  
    JOIN RecordType RecordTypeB 
        ON AccountB.RecordTypeId = RecordTypeB.Id 
    LEFT JOIN Account AccountB 
        ON Opportunity.AccountId = AccountB.Id  
    JOIN User UserB 
        ON AccountC.OwnerId = UserB.Id 
    LEFT JOIN Account AccountC 
        ON Opportunity.AccountId = AccountC.Id  
    LEFT JOIN Account AccountD 
        ON Opportunity.AccountId = AccountD.Id
    JOIN User UserC 
        ON AccountD.OwnerId = UserC.Id 
    JOIN UserRole UserRoleA 
        ON UserC.UserRoleId = UserRoleA.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

A nested join is nothing that you write in your query, but a technique the DBMS uses to perform a join.

When you join two tables, say, `from a join b on a.aa = b.bb`, the DBMS has several methods to put this into practise. For example it could read `a` and sort it by `aa`. Then it would read `b` and sort it by `bb`. Then it would read the two result list sequentially and write all the matches in a final result list.

Another method would be to read one record from `a`, then read `b` to find all matches on `aa = bb`. Then it would read the next record from `a` and read `b` again to find matches for this second record, and so on. This method is called a nested join.

You however, simply tell the DBMS what to join and on what criteria to join, but not what method to use. The DBMS will (hopefully) find the best method for each join.

As to your query: You select all records from `Opportunity`. Then you outer join the table `User`. So for some reason you expect some opportunities not to have an owner, but want a result row for the opportunity nonetheless. Same for `RecordType`, `Pricebook2` and `Account`; you expect some opportunities not to have a match in these tables, but want the opportunity still in the results. From the names we can gather that there are foreign keys on the columns, e.g. you cannot  store an opportunity with `RecordTypeId = 'X'` when `'X'` doesn't exist in `RecordType`. So you outer join obviously, because these columns are optional (nullable).

Then it gets queer. You try to outer join `Account` again. But this time you don't specify an ON clause. This is invalid SQL, but MySQL lets it slip. The join becomes a `CROSS JOIN` internally, i.e. you join every row you got so far with every account. Let's say you have 1000 records in `Opportunity` and 500 in `Account`, this makes 500,000 rows. Then you suddenly inner join `RecordType` again. But this time you want the record type for the accounts, not for the opportunities. You join on `AccountB.RecordTypeId = RecordTypeB.Id` So every row with an account with a `RecordTypeId` null gets dismissed, the others are kept. Then you have another `ON` clause which is misplaced. I don't know how MySQL interprets this. Either this results in a syntax error or its treated as a `WHERE` clause or its treated as part of the former `ON` clause. This is invalid and should raise an error, but so should the missing `ON` clause before which doesn't.

To make a long story short: you are doing things very wrong here. We'd have to know the expected results to get this straight.

Apart from this: Single quotes are for string literals:

```
'lalala' -- this is a string conform with the SQL standard
lalala   -- this is a name conform with the SQL standard
"lalala" -- this is a name conform with the SQL standard
         -- it could also be a string in MySQL violating the SQL standard
`lalala` -- this is a name in MySQL violating the SQL standard
```

Queries with many tables get easier to read with short alias names

```
FROM opprtunity o
JOIN User u ON u.Id = o.OwnerId
```